# ArcGIS Replica creation is too slow

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, enterprise-geodatabase, replication

I am trying to create a new Replica from my Oracle based SDE database.
Its takes more than 24 hours to create a 23 GB replica which is practically not working for me.

1. Is there any specific reason for this slow performance?
2. The source geodatabase is arcfmised. Could that be slowing it down.
3. The target FGDB location is on my computer. So network should not be the culprit.

I use following settings:

1. add all datasets and required tables from source geodatabase.
2. Set Replica Type to “ONE_WAY_REPLICA”.
3. Set target GDB file path in Geodatabase to replicate data to.
4. Set Replica name.
   5). In Advance Settings set values as follows:
   Replica Access Type --> FULL
   Expand Feature Classes and Tables --> ALL_ROWS
   Replicate Related Data --> GET_RELATED
5. Click on OK to create replica.

Comment: I am using arcmap 10.6.1

Comment: What version of Oracle DB and OS are you using? including RAM/SWAP space?

Comment: Oracle DB: 19c . It is hosted on Unix env. I can check  unix version and RAM/SWAP  space and get back

Comment: Database is hosted on: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.9 (Maipo)
Oracle 19c
RAM is 78G and Swap is 31G

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.